# If a value lies at EXACTLY two standard deviations from the mean, is it "usual data" or "unusual data"?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, terminology

If a value lies at EXACTLY two standard deviations from the mean, is it "usual data" or "unusual data"?

i.e., is usual data $-2\text{s.d.} < x < +2\text{s.d.}$,
or is it $-2\text{s.d.} \leq x \leq +2\text{s.d.}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that this question solely depends on your definition, and there's no underlying mathematical principle that would tell you a definite answer. Just consult your textbook on the definition, really.

Side note, I think [outlier detection tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) are much more well-defined in general - even though this is probably not what you are asking. "Unusual data" sounds very colloquial to me.